# How can I use a list function in CouchDB to generate a valid (/normal) ViewResults object?

Tags: view, couchdb, flask

I have a simple problem I need to solve, and list functions are my current attempt to do so. I have a view that generates almost what I need, but in certain cases there are duplicate entries that make it through when I send in edge-case parameters.

Therefore, I am looking to filter these extra results out. I have found examples of filtering, which I am using (see [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4298937/couchdb-views-remove-duplicates-and-order-by-time)). However, rather than generate HTML or XML or what-have-you, I just want a regular ol' view result. That is, the same kind of object that I would get if I queried CouchDB without a list function. It should have JSON data as normal and be the same in every way, except that it is missing duplicate results.

Any help on this would be appreciated! I have tried to send() data in quite a few different ways, but I usually get that "No JSON object could be decoded", or that indices need to be integers and not strings. I even tried to use the list to store every row until the end and send the entire list object back at once.

Example code (this is using an example [from this page](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Formatting_with_Show_and_List) to send data:

```
function(head, req) { 
    var row; var dupes = [];
    while(row=getRow()) { 
        if (dupes.indexOf(row.key) == -1) { 
            dupes.push(row.key); 
            send(row.value); 
        } 
    }; 
}
```

Lastly, I'm using Flask with Flask-CouchDB, and I'm seeing the aforementioned errors in the flask development server that I'm running.

Thanks! I can try to supply more details if need be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't you need to prepend a `[`, send a `,` after each row value except the last, and end with `]`? To actually mimic a view result, you'd actually need to wrap that in a JSON structure:

```
{"total_rows":0,"offset":0,"rows":[<your stuff here>]}
```

Comment: Simple! I'm not sure how I missed this. Thanks a lot!